# How to deal with incomplete html tags in Python?

Tags: python, html-parsing, wysiwyg

**Background:-** 
Am using a JS editor on my site. Now when I copy paste external text content on it, there are a few invalid/incomplete html tags that get pasted. ( But it is not made visible on the editor)
[image: Js Editor]

**Problem:-** 
Now when this data is posted, the alignment of the entire page gets screwed. How can I detect and change incomplete html tags if any. Should I use a html parser for this purpose ?
[image: Problem]

As you can see the edit and delete buttons have come out of the div. (The description or data has been copy pasted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the fantastic [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library for all your parsing needs. Buy now!

Comment: +1 for Beautiful Soup It is a great HTML parser and can handle malformed HTML pretty well.